# React router dom v6 Auth

Tags: reactjs, authentication, react-router-dom

I am having the hardest time trying to understand the react-router Auth. I have read the (horrible) [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/examples/auth) numerous times and i have followed MANY [tutorials](https://ui.dev/react-router-protected-routes-authentication/) on the web. Not a single one has worked. The [example](https://stackblitz.com/github/remix-run/react-router/tree/main/examples/auth?file=src/App.tsx) provided by React is written in typescript which makes it even harder to understand. Please help me figure this out.

They (React Dev Tutorial) use context and providers. But i cant seem to understand that either. IMO its very very convoluted unlike the rest of React-router.

When i run the login function from auth.js it seems to work and then it just resets the hook to false and never loads the next page. I feel like im so close but there is something wrong with the auth.js file?

**app.js**

```
function RequireAuth({children}) {
  let location = useLocation();
  const { authed } = UseAuth();

  console.log(authed);


  return authed ? children : <Navigate to="/" state={{from: location}}/>;
}
```

```
<Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <BrowserRouter location={history.location} navigator={history}>
          <AuthProvider>
          <Routes>

          <Route index element={<Login setData={setData} type={type}/>} />


              <Route path="adminDashboard" element={
                <RequireAuth redirectTo="/"> 
                  <AdminDashboard />
                </RequireAuth>
                } 
              />
              

              <Route path="userDashboard" element={
                <RequireAuth redirectTo="/"> 
                  <UserDashboard />
                </RequireAuth>
              } />
           </Routes>
          </AuthProvider>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
```

**login.js**

```
  const auth = UseAuth();
  auth.login();
```

**auth.js** *the auth.js file came from a seperate tutorial*

```
import * as React from "react";

const authContext = React.createContext({
  authed: false,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {}
});

export default function UseAuth() {
  return React.useContext(authContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [authed, setAuthed] = React.useState(false);
  let auth = UseAuth();

  const login = () => setAuthed(true, console.log(authed));
  const logout = () => setAuthed(false);

  let value = { authed, login, logout };


  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={value}>
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do appear to be close. The `useAuth` hook returns an object `{ authed, login, logout }`, but you are naming the *entire* object `auth` in your `RequireAuth` wrapper component and using *it* as the condition. It's a defined object so it will *always* be truthy. It looks like you just need to access the `authed` property from that object to know if a user has authenticated or not.

```
function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { authed } = useAuth();
  return auth ? children : <Navigate to="/" state={{from: location}}/>;
}
```

You also seem to have mixed up your auth context a bit. The state should reside in the context provider while the `useAuth` hook returns the provided value.

```
const authContext = React.createContext({
  authed: false,
  login: () => {},
  logout: () => {}
});

export default function useAuth() {
  return React.useContext(authContext);
}

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [authed, setAuthed] = React.useState(false);

  const login = () => setAuthed(true);
  const logout = () => setAuthed(false);

  return (
    <authContext.Provider value={{ authed, login, logout }}>
      {children}
    </authContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you drew i am one step closer !! Now when i run login() i can see that it is running via a console log. However, when i try to go to a different page `const { authed } = useAuth();` is always giving me `false`

Comment: @KeatonBenning Can you update your question to include a more complete and comprehensive code example so we can see how the parts of your code are composed and working together? If `AuthProvider` is wrapping the app and stable (i.e. not getting remounted) then there's no reason for its state to revert to false.

Comment: updated all of the code sections

Comment: also `const login = () => setAuthed(true, console.log(authed));` always logs false

Comment: @KeatonBenning Yeah, don't do that, you can't log state right after enqueueing the update as state updates are asynchronously processed. See this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-dom-v6-auth-ig7z5) copy/pasted from the code you just added.

Comment: **facepalm** ok so it has been working this entire time. Ive been entering /adminDashboard" onto the url and pressing enter instead of navigating (because of laziness lol). I didnt know that would make a difference. But when i refresh the page it will bring me back to the login page. How would i stop that from happening

Comment: never mind, figure that out. Pulled the token from localStorage and used it in the setState for authed. Is that an acceptable way of doing it?

Comment: @KeatonBenning Affirmative. Persist your auth state to localStorage when it changes, and initialize your auth state from localStorage when your app mounts.

Answer (score 2):

the useAuth returns 3 things authed, login() and logout().
so when u are calling `let auth = useAuth()`, auth is an object that contains all three of those.

Try deconstructing to useAuth returns like

`const { authed, login, logout } = useAuth()`

and use the authed instead